# R: How do I translate solve_LSAP into a dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a large assignment problem, and am using LSAP.  It works, but I am trying to get the output into a dataframe so that I can do more with it.  However, the documentation on the function says "An object of class "solve_LSAP" with the optimal assignment of rows to columns", with no further information on the data.  I cannot seem to crack open the class to break the data out into a more usable form.

I've provided their example code.

```
x <- matrix(c(5, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4), nrow = 3)
y <- solve_LSAP(x, maximum = FALSE)
y
```

Output:

```
Optimal assignment:
1 => 3, 2 => 1, 3 => 2
```

I have 200+ assignments, and the baseline output is simply not usable for me.  How can I translate it into a dataframe, or at least a matrix that looks something like the below?

```
Row Column
 1    3
 2    1
 3    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `solve_LSAP` returns column indices by each row, therefore comprising all you need for reconstruction:

```
len <- length(y)

parsedMat <- cbind(
  1:len,
  as.integer(y)
)

parsedMat

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    2
```

This can be turned into a solved matrix by:

```
solvedMat <- matrix(0, nrow = len, ncol = len)
solvedMat[parsedMat] <- 1

solvedMat

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
```

---

You can also turn this into a function that will return both outputs in form of a list, e.g.:

```
parseClueOutput <- function(x) {

  len <- length(x)

  parsedMat <- cbind(
    1:len,
    as.integer(x)
  )

  solvedMat <- matrix(0, nrow = len, ncol = len)
  solvedMat[parsedMat] <- 1

  return(
    list(
      parsedMat = parsedMat,
      solvedMat = solvedMat
    )
  )

}
```

And use it as:

```
parseClueOutput(y)

$parsedMat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    2

$solvedMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
```

---

As for the structure, the `solve_LSAP` is not really a complicated object, it's essentially a numeric vector which you can see with:

```
is.numeric(y)

[1] TRUE
```

Or:

```
str(y)

'solve_LSAP' num [1:3] 3 1 2
```

---

You can also turn the `solvedMat` or `parsedMat` into a dataframe easily - for example, the `parsedMat`:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(parsedMat), c('Row', 'Column'))

  Row Column
1   1      3
2   2      1
3   3      2
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me where I needed.  I just couldn't how to figure out how to get the data out.